# Dreamweaver vs aptana studio (for those who don't know coding)?

Tags: dreamweaver, aptana

I am a web designer and developer but I don't know any scripting language. And I am looking for a robust web development WYSIWYG like software that can write code for me automatically in javascript and php.

Comment: it is subjective and/or argumentative question in my sense.

Comment: @Harry: May be re-framing the question may help as it seems valid in broader context (WYSIWYG for non-programmers).

Comment: Be aware that, as a designer, if you don't know how to use HTML & CSS, your web pages will never look like your PSD. This is why designer and front-end developer are two different jobs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Id go with dreamweaver because is has the design view as well as the code view. Aptana is more for developers rather than designers and developers. Dreamweaver will write some code for you (and you'll find out later that its crap!) so it'll get you used to the languages.

I used to work in Dreamweaver when I first started but now I can't get enough of Aptana.

Comment: I use Dreamweaver for coding the front end. I recently installed aptana in order to write some php and test it but doesn't start up. Is it possibl to be any conflicts between those two???

Comment: Nope that shouldn't have anything to do between the two. And What doesn't start-up?

Comment: I've no idea. I've installed aptana succesfully (didn't got any errors etc) but when I click the desktop-icon to launch the programm it doesn't starts at all. I;m on Windows 7 64bit Home edition.

Comment: @Lykos, It's probably because of your Java installation. Aptana needs a 32-bit installation of Java, 64-bit won't work. Since you said your OS is 64-bit, I figured, that might be the problem. Better you check your Java installation.

Answer (score 1):

WYSIWYG will only generate HTML page and a little JS at best. You need to know coding to offer interactive functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You'll hate this answer but take some time to learn PHP and JavaScript - I stated off as a designer and tried to avoid code. Then instead of copying and pasting code hoping that it works I got to grips with the fundamentals of both languages and realised how easy it is and how there was nothing to fear.

Good resources are w3schools.com, stackoverflow (obviously) and my fav JavaScript books are DOM scripting by Jeremy Keith and Jeffrey Sambells and once you feel confident to learn some of the more advanced features of JavaScript, JavaScript Patterns by Stoyan Stefanov was helpful to me.

Like I say this doesn't actually answer your question. However Dreamweaver automatically produced a 700 line JS file for an interface action I wanted, using the resources above I did the same in an unobtrusive manner with 16 lines of code!

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread but im sure the debate still rages on LOL... i've been a devote DW user for many many many years (Like since 2000 or so). I am a coder/developer... I never use DW auto complete or anything like that. Primarily the reason i've stuck with it is because my FTP is RIGHT THERE!... HOWEVER, LOL, I just ran into a problem where I needed to recover a file (all these years and i've never needed this feature). Anyway I just ran across this thread [Recover Deleted Files in Aptana Studio 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523445/recover-deleted-files-in-aptana-studio-3) "By default Aptana Studio stores a history of up to 7 days if the file was within a project."... I guess i can live without having my ftp right there in the same program and just use filezilla. *sigh* lol. Also DW doesnt recognize keys which is a big let down but yea... anyway... I just started using Aptana Studio 3 so I hope I fall in love with it quickly lol I'm building my projects now :P

Comment: As a follow up LOL I've gone back to Dreamweaver LOL

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to clarify some stuff. Aptana **does have ftp**, and i even think it's easier to use than dreamweaver's ftp module...