# Recover Deleted Files in Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: php, eclipse, ide, aptana

I just accidentally deleted some files in Aptana Studio 3, and to my surprise, they're not in the recycle bin!

These are files that I would very much not like to lose, so does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve them?

I'm running a deleted file recovery program, but I don't expect it will help.

Comment: Not all deletes done from inside applications will go into the recycle bin.

Comment: So what should I do about it? Is it all permanently lost?

Comment: If its not backed up, it must not have been that important. Code should be under source control *and* backed up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to using the Aptana Studio 3 move file to trash when delete or clean file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7009384/how-to-using-the-aptana-studio-3-move-file-to-trash-when-delete-or-clean-file)

Comment: what did you use to recover your files?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default Aptana Studio stores a history of up to 7 days if the file was within a project.

Right click on the folder the file was in and choose "Restore from local History".

Source: Within "Help Contents" /help/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-87b.htm
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Recovering+a+Deleted+File+with+Local+History

Comment: Great, thanks! Unfortunately, I didn't see this until after recreating the project and restoring most of the files, so it wasn't able to help me, but this is an excellent feature to know about. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! This really saved me hours of rewriting code

Comment: Huge help! Thank you